# User guesses a number from 1-1000 using functions

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to make a program that prompts the user to guess a number from 1 to 1000. The program generates a random number and then the user has to guess the number until they get it right. The program alerts the user if their guess is too low or too high. Upon entering the right number, they are congratulated and asked if they want to run it again. I have read my book and even looked online for guidance, but against my best effort all it does is display the text field with the calculate button...no window messages or anything. Please help as I am stumped. This is what I have so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
            <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title>Assignment 9.25</title>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var inputField;
                    var guess;
                    var calculateButton;

                    function startGame() {
                    window.alert("Guess a number between 1 and 1000 in the text field.");
                    calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
                    //calculateButton.disable = true;
                    guessNum();
                        }

                        function randomNum(random) {
                            return Math.floor(1 + (Math.random() * 999));
                        }

                        function guessNum() {
                            inputField = document.getElementById("entry");
                            guess = parseFloat(inputField.value);

                            while (randomNum(random) != guess) {
                                if (randomNum(random) > guess) {
                                    window.alert("Too low. Try again.");
                                }
                                else if (randomNum(random) < guess) {
                                    window.alert("Too high. Try again.");
                                }
                            }

                            window.alert("Congratulations. You guessed the number!");
                            playAgain();
                        }

                        function playAgain() {
                            var again = window.prompt("Enter 'yes' to play again");
                                if (again == "yes") {
                                    Start();
                                    calculateButton.disabled = false;
                                else if (again == "no") {
                                            alert ("Thank you for playing! Goodbye!")
                                    calculateButton.disabled = true;
                                }
                        }

                        function Start() {
                            var calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
                            calculateButton.addEventListener( "click", startGame, false );
                        }

                    window.addEventListener("load", Start, false);
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="#">
                    <div>
                        <label>Your guess here:
                            <input id="entry" type="number">
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have a typo: inside `playAgain()` you're missing a closing `}` before the `else if`.

The browser error console can be very helpful in identifying this type of problem.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! I fixed it and it's still not doing anything. It appears to stop at startGame(). Am I using the wrong calling/pointer syntax to switch to the next function??

Answer (score 1):

There is a **`}`** missing in line 45

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
            <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title>Assignment 9.25</title>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var inputField;
                    var guess;
                    var calculateButton;

                    function startGame() {
                    window.alert("Guess a number between 1 and 1000 in the text field.");
                    calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
                    //calculateButton.disable = true;
                    guessNum();
                        }

                        function randomNum(random) {
                            return Math.floor(1 + (Math.random() * 999));
                        }

                        function guessNum() {
                            inputField = document.getElementById("entry");
                            guess = parseFloat(inputField.value);

                            while (randomNum(random) != guess) {
                                if (randomNum(random) > guess) {
                                    window.alert("Too low. Try again.");
                                }
                                else if (randomNum(random) < guess) {
                                    window.alert("Too high. Try again.");
                                }
                            }

                            window.alert("Congratulations. You guessed the number!");
                            playAgain();
                        }

                        function playAgain() {
                            var again = window.prompt("Enter 'yes' to play again");
                                if (again == "yes") {
                                    Start();
                                    calculateButton.disabled = false;
                                }
                                else if (again == "no") {
                                            alert ("Thank you for playing! Goodbye!")
                                    calculateButton.disabled = true;
                                }
                        }

                        function Start() {
                            var calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
                            calculateButton.addEventListener( "click", startGame, false );
                        }

                    window.addEventListener("load", Start, false);
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="#">
                    <div>
                        <label>Your guess here:
                            <input id="entry" type="number">
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery way](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/szpa33hz/) if you mind

```js
var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#numberrandom').text(a);
  });
  $('#calculate').bind('click',function(){
    entrynumber=$('#entry').val();
  if(entrynumber > a){
  alert('Your number is higher than it')
  }
  else if(entrynumber < a){
  alert('Your number is lower than it')
  }
  else if(entrynumber == a){
  alert('nice you won')
  location.reload();
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <body>
                <form action="#">
                    <div>
                        <label>Your guess here:
                            <input id="entry" type="number">
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate">
                        <span>generated number: </span><span id='numberrandom'></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </body>
```

Comment: I am not using Jquery for this,but it's good to know! Thanks!